# I need help to install RSS Owl in Ubuntu MATE 17.04

Tags: software-installation, java, mate

I decided to switch from Windows to Ubuntu MATE today. I've used RSS Owl in Windows for a while and like it and seeing that there is a version for Linux I would like to install it.

The problem is that I don't have much experience. I only know how to install stuff through the apt-get procedure and I can't find a working version of RSS Owl in any repository (it's in a Getdeb repository but it isn't updated, I tried that). Anyway, on the [RSS Owl webpage](http://www.rssowl.org/) there is a zip with the version for Linux.

Ok, so what do I do with it? Where do I put it?

It seems to be ready to just extract and put somewhere. I tried extracting right there in the downloads folder and running the RSSOwl executable and it gives me an error about not finding Java JRE at the appropriate location...

Can anybody help me out please?

Comment: Please put it in `/opt` or `/home/$USER`, then make sure java is in one of this paths when you run `echo $PATH` and run it should install...

Comment: Please post the results of `whereis java`

Comment: I put it in /home/$USER but it gives the same message. With regard to 'whereis java' it gives:  'java: /usr/share/java'

Comment: It will give the same message bcos java in not i your `system path`... what does `java --version` say

Comment: I think I understand what you mean by the paths for Java... but I don't understand the echo $PATH above, sorry. So how/where do I set the appropriate path?

Comment: first we need to check that java is installed(`java --version`) and where it is(`which java` or `whereis java`) so we can add that location to `$PATH`

Comment: When we know that we will add it to your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file so when you do `echo $PATH` we will see it...

Comment: We are looking for something in the line of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java`... But you will only have this if you had installed `java` previously...

Comment: You need to install java first: `sudo apt-get install default-jre`.

Comment: Ok, so I did  the 'java -version' and it says: "The programa "java" can be found in the following packages" and it goes on to list several options. So i'll go on and install it.

Comment: Now it works! The only problem was that Java wasn't installed, duh! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'd recommend you look into hosting a Tiny Tiny RSS installation, preferably on Ubuntu LTS with PostgreSQL. The Ubuntu package is called [tt-rss](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/tt-rss). You will be running a full LAMP webserver stack on a considerably specced computer that is always running (at home or in a datacenter) and you should setup automated database backups (some custom cron job or pgBackRest). Alternatives would be https://yunohost.org/ or https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/tiny-tiny-rss/ or a LXC containerized installation (e.g. Docker, LXD).

Comment: LiveWireBT, thanks for your comment. I obviously hardly understand anything you say because, as I said further up and as can be easily deduced from my comments, I just switched to Ubuntu from being an "average" Windows desktop user **this week**. To "host" an installation, a "webserver stack", "automated database backups", a "containerized installation"... are no doubt interesting, meaningful and appropriate terms for a linux or ubuntu expert or some sort of sysadmin but to me your recommendation comes of as somewhat IAmVerySmart-ish. In any case I will check out TT RSS, thanks.